# How do I generate random numbers with a certain interval?

Tags: javascript, jquery, random

I have this sample:

[link](https://codepen.io/cristian-marius/pen/ZEzdzQZ)

**CODE JS:**

```
for (var i=0; i < 5; i++) {
  var number = 1 + Math.floor(Math.random() * 20);
  console.log(number);
}
```

I want to generate numbers between 1 and 20 but with the following restrictions:

1. The numbers should not be duplicated
2. Exclude the first and last numbet (1,20)
3. The difference between the generated numbers must be at least 3 (ex: 4, 7,10  etc)

Can you please give me some tips on how I could do this?

A few simple examples would help me.

Thanks

Comment: "*Exclude the first and last numbet (1,20)*" so, you're not generating 1-20 but 2-19.

Comment: "*The difference between the generated numbers must be at least 3 (ex: 4, 7,10 etc)*" is that sequential difference or total? E.g., is a sequence `6 -> 9 -> 3` acceptable or not, since the difference between `9` and `3` is `6` but the difference between `3` and `6` is `3`

Comment: my example can be a starting point from which to modify together so that we get an example that can be used by someone else.

Comment: there may be even larger numbers: 3, 10, 14, 20
It doesn't have to be sequential

Comment: what about a result like `[ 9, 17, 14, 4]` then there is no value for the fifth value.

Answer (score 2):

You can keep a `Set` to check if the number is already generated and use recursion if so,
also for generating the numbers on a difference of 3, just multiply and divide the numbers by 3

```js
Math.floor(Math.random() * 20)

let generateRandom = (function(limit) {
  let set = new Set([20]);
  return function getRandom() {
    let random = Math.floor(2 + Math.floor(Math.random() * 20 / 3) * 3);
    if (set.has(random)) {
      return getRandom()
    } else {
      set.add(random)
      return random
    };
  }
})()

console.log(Array(5).fill(null).map(generateRandom))
```

Note: Remeber that you can generate a maximum of 5 numbers with the contraint, don't try to generate more else you will endup on `Range Error`.

Comment: You need to exclude 1 and 20 
_Exclude the first and last numbet (1,20)_

Comment: @angel.bonev thanks, missed that. updated the solution.

Comment: still 20 will not be excluded :(
[
  17,
  2,
  5,
  20,
  11,
  14
]

Comment: 2 + Math.floor(19/3) * 3 = 20

Comment: @angel.bonev updated, we can keep the 20 by default in the filter set.

Answer (score 1):

You could take a `Set` with possible numbers and take one of the numbers. Then delete the unwanted lower and upper values. Repeat until the wanted count.

```js
function get5() {
    var numbers = new Set(Array.from({ length: 18 }, (_, i) => i + 2)),
        result = [],
        random,
        i = 5, j;

    while (i--) {
        random = [...numbers][Math.floor(Math.random() * numbers.size)];
        result.push(random);
        for (j = random - 2; j < random + 3; j++) numbers.delete(j);
    }
    if (result[4] === undefined) return get5();
    return result;
}

console.log(get5());
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```js
var rendom = [];
while (rendom.length != 5) {
  var number = Math.floor(Math.random() * 18) + 2;
  let found = false;
  rendom.forEach(function(element) {
    if (element <= (number + 2) && element >= (number - 2)) {
      found = true;
    }
  });
  if (!found) {
    rendom.push(number);
  }
}

console.log(rendom);
```

Comment: when the difference is +2 and -2 i.e. 4, you cannot create 5 numbers that will endup on infinite loop.